# How to attach a UIPopover to a rectangle I have drawn

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipopovercontroller

I have an iPad app (XCode 4.6, ios 6.2, ARC and Storyboards).  I have drawn a GCRect on a position of a UIView.

```
    CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake( [appSelected.aPosX floatValue], [appSelected.aPosY floatValue],[appSelected.aPosW floatValue], [appSelected.aPosH floatValue]);
```

I have a method that does the drawing for me; this is the code for that method:

```
-(void)showHTMLHelp:(NSString *)htmlString pointTo:(id)target background:(UIColor *)bgColor  {

UIViewController* popoverContent = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UIView* popoverView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 300)];
popoverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:(CGFloat)1.0 alpha:(CGFloat)1.0];  //  frame color?
popoverContent.view = popoverView;

//resize the popover view shown in the current view to the view's size
popoverContent.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(200, 300);

//  add the UIWebView for RichText
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:popoverView.frame];
webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];  //  change background color here

//  add the webView to the popover
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:nil]];
[popoverView addSubview:webView];

//create a popover controller
popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];

//present the popover view non-modal with a refrence to the button pressed within the current view
if([target isKindOfClass: [UITextField class]])
    [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:((UITextField *)target).frame inView:self.view
                     permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
else if([target isKindOfClass: [UISegmentedControl class]])
    [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:((UISegmentedControl *)target).frame inView:self.view
                     permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
else if([target isKindOfClass: [UIButton class]])
    [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:((UIButton *)target).frame inView:self.view
                     permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
else 
    [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:*(CGRect *)CFBridgingRetain(target)
                                       inView:self.view
                     permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                     animated:YES];
```

}

Now I want to have a UIPopover point to that rectangle.  Since GCRect is a C structure, I can't figure out how to do it. This is what I tried, but obviously it's wrong.  How can I do this?  This is the code where I call the method to display the popover:

```
    PreferencesViewController *pvc = [[PreferencesViewController alloc] init];
[pvc showHTMLHelp:html pointTo: rectangle background:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Comment: What's the type of `target`? and I assume you mean `CGRect`, not `GCRect`.

Comment: **Question updated to show creation of CGRectMake**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is absolutely no problem with passing a C structure (or C primitive variable) to an Objective-C method. In fact, `presentPopoverFromRect:inView:permittedArrowDirections:animated:` takes a simple CGRect as you can tell by the header (or the documentation):

```
- (void)presentPopoverFromRect:(CGRect)rect 
                        inView:(UIView *)view 
      permittedArrowDirections:(UIPopoverArrowDirection)arrowDirections
                      animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

Simply call it like this:

```
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:rectangle
                                   inView:self.view
                 permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                 animated:YES];
```

And as Mar0ux already pointed out, it's `CGRect`, not `GCRect`. `CG` stands for [Core Graphics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreGraphics/Reference/CoreGraphics_Framework/_index.html).

Comment: Getting this build error:

 Sending '__strong id' to parameter of incompatible type 'CGRect' (aka 'struct CGRect')

Comment: That means `target` is an Obj-C object, not a `CGRect`. What is `target`?

Comment: **I added all of the pertinent code to the Qustion.  Sorry it was incomplete; I normally don't leave out all of the code**

Comment: What are you doing in the last `else` block? You're sending `target` to the method. As I said, you have to send a `CGRect`.

Comment: *target* is one of the parameters passed to the method that does the drawing... I know it's confusing, but that was my fault when I wrote the question :-{

If you look at where I call the method, you will see it is a GCRect...

Comment: Fixed it, sort of... the major problem was calling the method in another class to do the drawing, where it requires a target class; I was using (id) to satisfy the call, but then in the code was checking which class was being represented.  Since CGRect is not a class, it didn't like it.  So, I took the code and moved it to the calling class.  Thanks for your help... I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

May i ask you why you are sending an CGRect and casting it to 'id'? Where is the sense?! I would prefer to change your parameter type to CGRect too.

Kind regards.